# Creating a simple HTTP python server to handle broken pipe

Tags: python, http, server

I create a simple python http server and I want it to display only files from a directory I want to, thus changing always returning "Hello world!" and also how could I handle the broken pipe errors? I tried to do a `try catch` there but I'm not sure if it's working:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 8089

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser 
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Hello World !")
        return

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started http server on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    #Wait forever for incoming http requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
except socket.error:
    pass
```

This is my Error:

```
someIP - - [25/Dec/2019 09:17:11] "GET someFILE HTTP/1.0" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 293, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 657, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 716, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Broken pipe from where?

Comment: Well, let's say I have more files here on the server (thus asking how would I make a directory the "root" of the website), and some user might make a request to some file and he will exit the browser or something while getting the request and this will generate a broken pipe and my server will go down.

Comment: @J.Homer are you talking about broken pipe on your ssh connection

Comment: @MohitC I've updated the question with an error log so you could see what I'm talking about

Comment: I dont see any broken pipe error in log

Comment: @MohitC Sorry, haven't pasted the whole error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example which follows is the basic example of creating basic web server for serving the static files. Additional comments you can find inside the code, with one additional note: 403 Forbidden implementation can be replaced with file indexing page, for what you need to do the additional generation of it (according to your question, this is out of scope for now.)

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from os import curdir, sep, path


class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200) #Request received, sending OK status
        self.end_headers()
        try:
            if(path.isdir(self.path)): #Checking if user requested access to dirrectory (not to a particular file)
                self.send_response(403)
                self.wfile.write(str.encode("Listing of directories not permited on this server")) #Preventing directory listing, in case you dont want to allow file indexing.
            else: #If user is requesting access to a file, file content is read and displayed.
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'rb')
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
        except IOError: #Covering the 404 error, in case user requested non-existing file
            print("File "+self.path+" not found")
            self.send_response(404)


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: And also how would I set a directory to be the "root" of the website? And not just only showing "hello world"?

Comment: @J.Homer: You are switching setting the root by overriding do_GET and its self.path. I still dont have full understanding of what you want, but the upper modified example shall list the content of current folder.

Comment: I want to make a simple HTTP web server for my blog and I'm not really experienced in python web servers and so, and I was using the "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8089" to get a simple web HTTP server woking but that is really unreliable and I was keep getting the "broken pipe" error mentioned above and wanted to get a way around it. Also the modified version doesn't really sends the response, what I mean is doesn't show the content of the files..

Comment: Then what kind of HTTP server should I create/?

Comment: But my blog will only contain html files or css and so on, not really php or smth else

Comment: I've alerted code proposed, according to your additional info. Taken over from acmesystems.it

Comment: Definetely! but you also said that you don't recommend that, why so? and Also what if I have multiple subfolders how should I deal with that? How does the ```python simplehttpserver``` deal with that?

Comment: In case serving the static files, then the  simplehttpserver is okay choice. In case you need serving extensive server side scripts (i.e. PHP), then it is not a good choice. Regarding the folders and subfolders: you are proclaiming your main folder as the root folder for the web server. Later on, you are referring to the files in child directories, and it should work regularly.

Comment: I should refer each file individually?

Comment: Finally, I've managed to switch to another machine on which I could actually test the code. I've again alerted code in this post, and you now have a fully working solution for serving static files @J.Homer

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain a little what you did there? and how does that made it work?

Comment: Also how do you change the permissions? Why the "Listing of directories not permitted"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204835/discussion-between-user5214530-and-j-homer).

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the same error earlier

My Code :

```
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL

signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
```

Paste it in the end and it should work!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! And how would I implement that using the ```python -m SimpleHTTPServer``` command? Also what ```SIG_DFL``` does?